Align selected item text with label text in MUI select
I have the following custom component that renders a status filter
<Stack direction="row" spacing={2} alignItems="center">
  <Typography variant="body2" component="label" id="status-filter-label">
    Filter by Status:
  </Typography>
  <FormControl size="small">
    <Select
      labelId="status-filter-label"
      disableUnderline
      variant="standard"
      value={statusFilter}
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
      <MenuItem value={Status.All}>
        <Typography variant="body2">All</Typography>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={Status.Open}>
        <Typography variant="body2">Open</Typography>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={Status.InProgress}>
        <Typography variant="body2">In Progress</Typography>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={Status.Approved}>
        <Typography variant="body2">Approved</Typography>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={Status.Rejected}>
        <Typography variant="body2">Rejected</Typography>
      </MenuItem>
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
</Stack>

This does not align the label text with the selected value text

in the DOM inspection I see that the div that has the role combobox would need a align-content of end but cant find the property to set.

How to align it correctly?
